# Battery never stops charging!

Tags: linux, power-management, battery

I have a Manjaro Xfce latest version. My laptop is a Lenovo Z500.

I've recently noticed that my batter is always at %99 and keeps on charging.

[image]

Is there a way to make it stop charging at 99%, or make it continue to the 100% and stop charging there? I had a Windows installed when i got the laptop and I used to be able to make it stop charging the battery after 56%, is this possible on Linux as well?